# Site has been hacked

Tags: php

When I search my site in the google search, my site shows up in the first place but, it is showing my site has been hacked, It's been 2 months and still it is showing the same message when I google it . my site is built in PHP.

I know a little bit of technical stuff because I am a beginner in developing , I tried to find out and I checked in the Title, Meta, Image descriptions tags and page title and page description but did not see any difference in my text. Even my technical team could not figure it out.

I am so stressed out please help me guys. I have attached a picture on how it is showing in the google search.

[image]

Comment: are you saying its never been hacked and the goggle search  "snippet" is wrong? have you followed googles advise: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/190597?hl=en

Comment: I followed it, but no change

Comment: you will just have to wait, until goggle re-indexes it. I assume its been all fixed?

Comment: Do you use any actions links? mod_rewrite? SQL_Connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `site may be hacked` keyword in database and Also if you are using any CMS then update to latest version so updated version contain latest valunerability fixes.
Dont use any `nulled` version plugin becasue that might contain malicious code which is encrypted in `base64` or `eval`. and you can submit your website to google for review so they can remove  site may be hacked if site is clean.

As per you that Hacked content not there in viewsouce then you can submit to Google for review.Within 72 hours they will replay.
you can follow below link to  submit your website to Google so they can review and remove site may be hacked in Google search result

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But do you know how long it takes for review and how can i remove this text

Comment: 72 hours they will take to review

Comment: "Message!!      Sorry Admin. Your Site Has Been hacked By Apearl Black Team Don't Panic !!! fucking you admin ! Your security system has an extremely ugly and I think it was ..."

Comment: Is there any way that I can manually remove this text                                                                                               "Message!!                                                                                               Sorry Admin. Your Site Has Been hacked By Apearl Black Team Don't Panic !!! fucking you admin ! Your security system has an extremely ugly and I think it was ... "

Comment: check in database and also if you are suing wordpres or any other cms update to lates version .also update plugins .you can use sukri website to check malware

Comment: Thank you @vision. it really helped me

Comment: @mural.glad to here it helped you

Comment: @mural, could you solve it? It happens to me too. Pls advise if you did anything in particular that help you get it sorted out. Thanks in advance